# Unable to position text

Tags: html, css, web

I center-aligned some text and then positioned it using top:20%. It worked fine, but when I added a paragraph under it, the element just moved back into the beginning position(the top:20% didn't take effect).

```
    <style>
    .yes{
            width : 100%;
            height : 50%;
            background-color: red;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .yes a{
            font-size : 300%;
            position: relative;
            top : 20%;
        }
    </style>

    <div class = "yes">
    <a>Title</a>
    <p></p></div>
```

Update: For some reason on jsfiddle, the div does not show up as 50% height and thus it's difficult to see the problem I'm referring too. Here is a link to view the code. Simply remove the p tag to see the effect: http://liveweave.com/owjs3W#&togetherjs=xwdArBqd5t

Comment: Make a fiddle. I couldn't repeat it with your code.

Comment: I think `top: 20%` will take effect when you'll set `display: block;` for `.yes a`

Comment: @shukshin.ivan When I make a fiddle, the div does not take up 50% of the screen. So it doesn't take effect.

Comment: @shukshin.ivan Here's the pastebin to my entire code : http://pastebin.com/Z5hABuDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to repeat and verify it? The following snippet works fine in last Chrome. Title doesn't move after paragraph added.

UPD. The situation concerned can be repeated with a tall wrapper. So the solution is just to make `a` `display` to `block`.

```css
    .wrp{height:400px;}
    .yes{
            width : 100%;
            height : 50%;
            background-color: red;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .yes a{
            display:block;
            font-size : 300%;
            position: relative;
            top : 20%;
        }
```

```html
<div class="wrp">
    <div class="yes">
        <a>Title</a>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="wrp">
    <div class="yes">
        <a>Title</a>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! This seems to have done it. Mind explaining what display : block does? I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: It's a good question *why* `inline` element behaves as a `block` one when it is alone in a div. It worth to know that.

Answer (score -1):

you have to encapsulate the style inside a class tag not an id tag.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .yes{
            width : 100%;
            height : 50%;
            background-color: red;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .yes a{
            font-size : 300%;
            position: relative;
            top : 20%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="yes">
        <a>Title</a>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[see it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/ok8d8fsh/)

The Difference is the following:
Id's should be Unique and only be set to one element on the Document.
Classes can be set to multiple Elements in the Dom.

Comment: *"not an id tag"* - What "id" tag? I don't see `#` or `id="x"` in their code.

Comment: you need to remove everything regarding id's.